# Biblatex: Add an image in a bib entry

Tags: biblatex

I have a list of publications I need to include in a document. For some of the publications authors are ordered alphabetically while for the others, this order depends on their contribution in the cited work. This list of publications looks like that:

```
@book{keyA,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  keywords = { conf },
}

@book{keyB,
  author = {Author, B.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  keywords = { journal },
}

@book{keyC,
  author = {Author, C.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  keywords = { conf },
}

@book{keyD,
  author = {Author, D.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  keywords = { conf },
}
```

And the .tex file is something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sorting=none, style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\section{Bibliography}
\printbibliography[keyword={conf},heading=none]

\end{document}
```

The file as output looks like the screenshot below.

[image]

What I'm trying to do is to add a small image I created (abc.png) at the beginning of the alphabetically ordered entries. Let's say entry "keyC" has a list of authors alphabetically ordered, the results would be like that:

[image]

I have no idea how to figure this out. I am not even sure whether it's doable... Maybe something with a `\renewcommand` and a way to identify the affected entries (Is it possible to have multiple keywords and filter the `\printbibliography` with just one of them?).

Any idea? Suggestion?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You mean at the beginning of each entry, at each set of entries, or at the beginning of the bibliography as a whole? Also, it would increase the chance of you receiving a good answer if you provided a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407), beginning with `\documentclass`, ending with `\end{document}` and including some sample bib entries.

Comment: Thanks! The challenge is I would like to add this image at the beginning of a subset of the entries. Let's say my "intconf" list contains 10 entries, I would like to add an image at the beginning of maybe 3 entries that have the authors alphabetically ordered. I'm gonna work on a more complete example.

Comment: Please try to be specific about the desired result. For that and for the MWE you can edit your question (link available on the bottom left).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a category and include the selected entries with `\addtocategory`. Biblatex's standard styles provide the macro `begentry` as an easy hook into the beginning of the bibdriver, `biblatex-ieee` does too. So, you can redefine `begentry` to conditionally include the images for every entry of the category:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sorting=none, style=ieee]{biblatex}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{intconf}

\addtocategory{intconf}{keyC}

\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{\ifcategory{intconf}{%
    \raisebox{-2pt}{\includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{abc.png}}\addspace}%
}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\section{Bibliography}
\printbibliography[keyword={conf},heading=none]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!

Comment: FWIW I would prefer `\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{}` over `\AtEveryBibitem{}` in this case, but that is probably a matter of taste.

Comment: @moewe Because it would then be executed within the driver rather than before it? I agree that it would be more proper. But I didn't think of that then.

Comment: Indeed. I feel that `\AtEveryBibitem` should not print anything, but `begentry` is a good place to print text. As I say it's a matter of taste.

Comment: On the other hand, `\AtEveryBibitem` is a sort of `\xapptobibmacro{begentry}` so I usually recur to it first without having to worry what's in there (even though, I know it is empty in the standard styles). But you are right, I will update the answer.