# How can I get the open-access-symbol for manually open-access declared publications with biblatex-ext-oa?

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-ext

Following the example shown at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/459488/98739 I extended it with another publication (`Bossert:788839`).
This article is not found by the unpaywall API (I do not expect that), but it is open access via Zenodo and has a DOI.
I read in the biblatex-ext manual that I can declare such publications also "open access" by adding `DOI+an = {openaccess}` (page 48), nevertheless this is neglected when I use the option `openaccess=doiapi`.

> My question is: How can I use the Unpaywall API for (most of) the publication entries and manually set this status for some of them?

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage[doiapi=true, symbolpackage=tikz, symbol=oanet]{biblatex-ext-oa}
% symbolpackage=tikz chooses open access symbols drawn in TikZ
% symbol=oanet gives an the open access symbol from
% open-access.net (https://open-access.net/),
% logo by
% Medien + Design
% Center for Digital Systems
% Competence Center for E-Learning and Multimedia
% Freie Universität Berlin
% CC BY 4.0 (https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/)
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{openaccess=doiapi}

\SetDOIAPIMail{m@you.com}% <- this MUST be set for doiapi
%\SetDOIAPICacheExpiration{15}% if you like, you can set the expiration period
                              % for the cache here, default is seven days

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
% this article is open access at the source
@article{valfort,
  author   = {Valfort, Aurore-Cécile and Launay, Caroline and Sémon, Marie
              and Delattre, Marie},
  title    = {Evolution of mitotic spindle behavior during the first
              asymmetric embryonic division of nematodes},
  journal  = {PLOS Biology},
  date     = {2018-01},
  volume   = {16},
  number   = {1},
  pages    = {1-23},
  doi      = {10.1371/journal.pbio.2005099},
}
% has open access version on Harvard DASH
@article{kucsko,
  author   = {G. Kucsko and P. C. Maurer and N. Y. Yao and M. Kubo
              and H. J. Noh and P. K. Lo and H. Park and M. D. Lukin},
  title    = {Nanometre-scale thermometry in a living cell},
  journal  = {Nature},
  volume   = {500},
  number   = {7460},
  pages    = {54--58},
  doi      = {10.1038/nature12373},
  date     = {2013},
}
% has open access version on the arXiv
@article{randall,
  author   = {Lisa Randall and Raman Sundrum},
  title    = {Large Mass Hierarchy from a Small Extra Dimension},
  journal  = {Physical Review Letters},
  year     = {1999},
  volume   = {83},
  number   = {17},
  pages    = {3370--3373},
  doi      = {10.1103/physrevlett.83.3370},
}
% second open access at HAL
@article{abiakle,
  author     = {Abi Akle, Audrey and Stéphanie Minel and Bernard Yannou},
  title      = {Information visualization for selection in Design by Shopping},
  journal    = {Research in Engineering Design},
  volume     = {28},
  number     = {1},
  year       = {2017},
  pages      = {99--117},
  doi        = {10.1007/s00163-016-0235-2},
}
% no open access that I know of
@Article{Bossert:788839,
  Author     = {Bossert, Lukas C.},
  Title      = {Mit »biber --tool« Bibliografieeinträge bearbeiten},
  JournalTitle = {Die TEXnische Komödie},
  Year       = {2020},
  DOI        = {10.5281/zenodo.3784922},
  DOI+an     = {openaccess},
  Location   = {Heidelberg},
  Pages      = {24--33},
  Publisher  = {DANTE},
  Volume     = {2}
}
\end{filecontents*}


\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\kant[1]
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do this is to explicitly say that the best open access URL is the DOI by passing `openacess = doi,` as a per-entry option.

```
@article{Bossert:788839,
  author     = {Bossert, Lukas C.},
  title      = {Mit »biber --tool« Bibliografieeinträge bearbeiten},
  journaltitle = {Die TEXnische Komödie},
  year       = {2020},
  options    = {openaccess=doi},
  doi        = {10.5281/zenodo.3784922},
  location   = {Heidelberg},
  pages      = {24--33},
  publisher  = {DANTE},
  volume     = {2}
}
```

In full

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage[doiapi=true, symbolpackage=tikz, symbol=oanet]{biblatex-ext-oa}
% symbol=oanet gives an the open access symbol from
% open-access.net (https://open-access.net/),
% logo by
% Medien + Design
% Center for Digital Systems
% Competence Center for E-Learning and Multimedia
% Freie Universität Berlin
% CC BY 4.0 (https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/)
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{openaccess=doiapi}

\SetDOIAPIMail{m@you.com}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
% this article is open access at the source
@article{valfort,
  author   = {Valfort, Aurore-Cécile and Launay, Caroline and Sémon, Marie
              and Delattre, Marie},
  title    = {Evolution of mitotic spindle behavior during the first
              asymmetric embryonic division of nematodes},
  journal  = {PLOS Biology},
  date     = {2018-01},
  volume   = {16},
  number   = {1},
  pages    = {1-23},
  doi      = {10.1371/journal.pbio.2005099},
}
% has open access version on Harvard DASH
@article{kucsko,
  author   = {G. Kucsko and P. C. Maurer and N. Y. Yao and M. Kubo
              and H. J. Noh and P. K. Lo and H. Park and M. D. Lukin},
  title    = {Nanometre-scale thermometry in a living cell},
  journal  = {Nature},
  volume   = {500},
  number   = {7460},
  pages    = {54--58},
  doi      = {10.1038/nature12373},
  date     = {2013},
}
% has open access version on the arXiv
@article{randall,
  author   = {Lisa Randall and Raman Sundrum},
  title    = {Large Mass Hierarchy from a Small Extra Dimension},
  journal  = {Physical Review Letters},
  year     = {1999},
  volume   = {83},
  number   = {17},
  pages    = {3370--3373},
  doi      = {10.1103/physrevlett.83.3370},
}
% second open access at HAL
@article{abiakle,
  author     = {Abi Akle, Audrey and Stéphanie Minel and Bernard Yannou},
  title      = {Information visualization for selection in Design by Shopping},
  journal    = {Research in Engineering Design},
  volume     = {28},
  number     = {1},
  year       = {2017},
  pages      = {99--117},
  doi        = {10.1007/s00163-016-0235-2},
}
@article{Bossert:788839,
  author     = {Bossert, Lukas C.},
  title      = {Mit »biber --tool« Bibliografieeinträge bearbeiten},
  journaltitle = {Die TEXnische Komödie},
  year       = {2020},
  options    = {openaccess=doi},
  doi        = {10.5281/zenodo.3784922},
  location   = {Heidelberg},
  pages      = {24--33},
  publisher  = {DANTE},
  volume     = {2}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\kant[1]
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Bibliography with open access symbol for all entries.]

---

Another way would be to disable `openaccess=doiapi,` locally for the relevant entry by setting `openaccess=auto,` (which uses the open access detection heuristic) in the `options` field.

Note that the `openaccess` annotation for the `doi` field must contain an `=` due to the specific syntax of field annotations.

So we would end up with

```
@article{Bossert:788839,
  author     = {Bossert, Lukas C.},
  title      = {Mit »biber --tool« Bibliografieeinträge bearbeiten},
  journaltitle = {Die TEXnische Komödie},
  year       = {2020},
  options    = {openaccess=auto},
  doi        = {10.5281/zenodo.3784922},
  doi+an     = {=openaccess},
  location   = {Heidelberg},
  pages      = {24--33},
  publisher  = {DANTE},
  volume     = {2}
}
```

In full

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage[doiapi=true, symbolpackage=tikz, symbol=oanet]{biblatex-ext-oa}
% symbol=oanet gives an the open access symbol from
% open-access.net (https://open-access.net/),
% logo by
% Medien + Design
% Center for Digital Systems
% Competence Center for E-Learning and Multimedia
% Freie Universität Berlin
% CC BY 4.0 (https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/)
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{openaccess=doiapi}

\SetDOIAPIMail{m@you.com}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
% this article is open access at the source
@article{valfort,
  author   = {Valfort, Aurore-Cécile and Launay, Caroline and Sémon, Marie
              and Delattre, Marie},
  title    = {Evolution of mitotic spindle behavior during the first
              asymmetric embryonic division of nematodes},
  journal  = {PLOS Biology},
  date     = {2018-01},
  volume   = {16},
  number   = {1},
  pages    = {1-23},
  doi      = {10.1371/journal.pbio.2005099},
}
% has open access version on Harvard DASH
@article{kucsko,
  author   = {G. Kucsko and P. C. Maurer and N. Y. Yao and M. Kubo
              and H. J. Noh and P. K. Lo and H. Park and M. D. Lukin},
  title    = {Nanometre-scale thermometry in a living cell},
  journal  = {Nature},
  volume   = {500},
  number   = {7460},
  pages    = {54--58},
  doi      = {10.1038/nature12373},
  date     = {2013},
}
% has open access version on the arXiv
@article{randall,
  author   = {Lisa Randall and Raman Sundrum},
  title    = {Large Mass Hierarchy from a Small Extra Dimension},
  journal  = {Physical Review Letters},
  year     = {1999},
  volume   = {83},
  number   = {17},
  pages    = {3370--3373},
  doi      = {10.1103/physrevlett.83.3370},
}
% second open access at HAL
@article{abiakle,
  author     = {Abi Akle, Audrey and Stéphanie Minel and Bernard Yannou},
  title      = {Information visualization for selection in Design by Shopping},
  journal    = {Research in Engineering Design},
  volume     = {28},
  number     = {1},
  year       = {2017},
  pages      = {99--117},
  doi        = {10.1007/s00163-016-0235-2},
}
% no open access that I know of
@article{Bossert:788839,
  author     = {Bossert, Lukas C.},
  title      = {Mit »biber --tool« Bibliografieeinträge bearbeiten},
  journaltitle = {Die TEXnische Komödie},
  year       = {2020},
  options    = {openaccess=auto},
  doi        = {10.5281/zenodo.3784922},
  doi+an     = {=openaccess},
  location   = {Heidelberg},
  pages      = {24--33},
  publisher  = {DANTE},
  volume     = {2}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\kant[1]
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Bibliography with open access symbol for all entries]

Comment: Perfect, I was missing the locally option `options    = {openaccess=auto},` in the manual. Thank you very much.

Comment: @LukasCB Actually, I just had a look at the documentation myself and found a quicker alternative.

Comment: excellent! this is very simple and effective