# Add icons to bibliography style in scrbook

Tags: bibtex, scrbook, ieee-style, bibliographystyle

I am trying to get result like below image.
[image]

Currently I get it by adding a line in the author field:

```
    Author = {{\includegraphics[scale = 0.03]{bullet3}}  Mosco Vicent}
```

but I want to find a way to do it automatically and adding different icons depending on the source. I know something similar can be done in beamer.

I think the best way is to create a custom bibliography style. I am using the following style:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZXw4UA_d2rbcegvGrTGuMLuAdsiGE8XY/view?usp=sharing

Can someone guide me to the solution?

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example (MWE).

Comment: Hello thanks for commenting, I have only been able to obtain something similar with the line of code that is in the post. Which I add manually, I have no idea how to approach the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by editing `.bst` bibliography style file: Find and Replace

```
FUNCTION {start.entry}
{ newline$
  "\bibitem{" write$
  cite$ write$
  "}" write$
  newline$
  ""
  initialize.prev.this.status
}
```

By

```
FUNCTION {start.entry}
{ newline$
  "\bibitem{" write$
  cite$ write$
  "}"  "\faBook\ " * write$
  newline$
  ""
  initialize.prev.this.status
}
```

and include `\usepackage{fontawesome}` package in your preamble and compile your file. Its output should be something like this:

[image]

You can change its color by `\textcolor{blue}{\faBook}` (here it is blue and you can use any color) after loading `\usepackage{xcolor}` and use it instead of `\faBook` in the above code. i.e.

```
FUNCTION {start.entry}
{ newline$
  "\bibitem{" write$
  cite$ write$
  "}"  "\textcolor{blue}{\faBook}\ " * write$
  newline$
  ""
  initialize.prev.this.status
}
```

[here is a list of icons](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/fonts/fontawesome/doc/fontawesome.pdf) you can use from `awesome` package. (In my example it is `\faBook`. You can use `\faNewspaperO` also.). You can also use [`awesome5`](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/fonts/fontawesome5/doc/fontawesome5.pdf) which is newer and has more icons than `awesome` package.

---

**Update:**
You can insert image using `\includegraphics` as follow: (Don't forget loading `\usepackage{graphicx}`)

```
FUNCTION {start.entry}
{ newline$
  "\bibitem{" write$
  cite$ write$
  "}" "\includegraphics[width=7pt, height=10pt]{Image-root}" * write$
  newline$
  ""
  initialize.prev.this.status
}
```

After adding appropriate `Image-root` in the above its output should be something like this:

[image]

Or you can do it without editing `.bst` file. Just by adding the following in your preamble: (Inspired by [Andrew Swann's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/254512/108724))

```
 \makeatletter
 \def\@bibitem#1{\item\if@filesw \immediate\write\@auxout
    {\string\bibcite{#1}{\value{\@listctr}}}\fi\ignorespaces}
 \def\@biblabel#1{[#1] \includegraphics[width=7pt, height=10pt]{image-root}}
 \makeatother
```

[image]

Comment: My answer prints a logo for all bib items and all logos are same as each other. I think it is possible to change the above code such that for papers the logo is paper icon and for books the logo is book icon.

Comment: hi thanks for the answer, can I use \includegraphics to add my custom icon?

Comment: That is why I am asking for a MWE. I don't know if you are using `biblatex` or not? if yes see [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/411050/108724).

Comment: Hello sorry for not being of much help, I understand that I use bibtex. I already managed to get it working by editing the .bst file. One question can I add an option for each type of information source?